# Access denied when attempting to open copied word doc with OpenXML

Tags: c#, openxml, mailmerge

I'm attempting to automate a mail merge process using c#, a DataSet, and OpenXML. I have a complete working example when running locally. When publishing to our webserver however, I'm getting an Access Denied error despite even going so far as to grant Full Control everywhere.

Here is the code leading up to the error message:

```
        try
        {
            var strTemplateTestFile = strMergeBuildingLocation.Replace(".docx", "_Test.docx");

            // Don't continue if the template file name is not found
            if (!File.Exists(strTemplateFileName))
                throw new Exception("TemplateFileName (" + strTemplateFileName + ") does not exist");

            foreach (var dr in dsData.Tables[0].Rows)
            {

                    string strFileName;

                if (doesDestinationExist(strMergeBuildingLocation))
                {
                    File.Copy(strTemplateFileName, strTemplateTestFile, true);
                    strFileName = strTemplateTestFile;
                }
                else
                {
                    File.Copy(strTemplateFileName, strMergeBuildingLocation, true);
                    strFileName = strMergeBuildingLocation;
                }

                var pkg = Package.Open(strFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
                using (var docGenerated = WordprocessingDocument.Open(pkg))
```

The problem falls within the last line upon attempting to open docGenerated.

The error message I'm receiving is:

> Access to the path 'docx path' is denied.

The file copies as expected and is able to be opened and modified manually. There's nothing within the folders that would be restricting access to the file. Does anyone have any thoughts as to what the issue could be?

Comment: Is it marked as read-only?

Comment: I'd suggest you to use [Sysinternals Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx)  to detect the exact point which is causing the access denied error. It always help me.

Comment: @tnw, it is not marked as being Read-Only, no.

Comment: @Luizgrs, thank you for the suggestion to use ProcMon (also discovered Process Explorer in the process). It did help track the issue.

There were unfortunately no permissions issues aside from the documents themselves being set to Read-Only when they were copied to their final destination. Lesson learned to not assume that non-Read-Only files stay that way when they are copied.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here in this line.

```
var pkg = Package.Open(strFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
            using (var docGenerated = WordprocessingDocument.Open(pkg))
```

Here you are trying to open the document twice.

Try this,

```
/* Open WordProcessing document package based on filename */
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------Start
    public static WordprocessingDocument OpenPackage(WordprocessingDocument package, string inputFileName, bool editable)
    {
        bool copied = false;
        while (!copied)
        {
            try
            {
                package = WordprocessingDocument.Open(inputFileName, editable);
                copied = true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                if (e is FileFormatException)
                {
                    package = null;
                    break;
                }
                if (e is IOException)
                {
                    copied = false;
                }
                if (e is ZipException)
                {
                    package = null;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return package;
    }
```

This will give you the WordprocessingDocument package if it exists and available. If file does not exists, null will be returned.If file locked, will open package when file released.
Hope this helps.! Thank you!